# Hide download link for 10 seconds? js

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

hey, how can I have my download link hidden, and make a count down type thing. Maybe have it count down from 10 and once it's done that have the download link appear, it would be best to do it in js right?

does anyone know how to do this? :D

Thanks

Comment: Ryan Mitchell's answer is correct, but if you don't secure the link for 10 seconds on the server side as well, your download protection will be childishly easy to bypass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval for this. setInterval behaves like a timer, where you can run a certain function periodically. Something like this should do the work(untested):

```
$(".link").hide();

var iteration = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(iteration++ >= 10) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(".link").show();
        $(".counter").hide();
    }

    $(".counter").text(10 - iteration);
}, 1000);
```

This will initially hide the download link and run a function every second which counts down from 10. When we reaced ten, we hide the counter and show the link. ClearTimeout is used so that we don't count after we reached ten. Easy as dell.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this function is using jQuery to find the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Complete example:

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<a id="download_link" href="download.zip" style="display:none;">Download</a>
<noscript>JavaScript needs to be enabled in order to be able to download.</noscript>
<script type="application/javascript">
(function(){
   var message = "%d seconds before download link appears";
   // seconds before download link becomes visible
   var count = 10;
   var countdown_element = document.getElementById("countdown");
   var download_link = document.getElementById("download_link");
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
      // if countdown equals 0, the next condition will evaluate to false and the else-construct will be executed
      if (count) {
          // display text
          countdown_element.innerHTML = "You have to wait %d seconds.".replace("%d", count);
          // decrease counter
          count--;
      } else {
          // stop timer
          clearInterval(timer);
          // hide countdown
          countdown_element.style.display = "none";
          // show download link
          download_link.style.display = "";
      }
   }, 1000);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function.  You can do something like:

```
function displayLink() {
  document.getElementById('link_id').style.display = 'block';
}

setTimeout(displayLink, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var WAIT_FOR_SECONDS = 10;
var DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_ID = "btnDownload";

if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener("load", displayDownloadButton, false);
} else {
    document.body.onload = displayDownloadButton;
}

function displayDownloadButton(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        _e(DOWNLOAD_BUTTON_ID).style.display = "";
    }, WAIT_FOR_SECONDS*1000);
}

function _e(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```